# Calculating individual orders in this Probability question

Tags: probability, permutations

I have a probability question to solve:

Question: Three different orders are to be mailed to three suppliers. However, an absent minded secretary gets the orders mixed up and sends them randomly. If a match refers to the fact that a suppliers receives the correct order, find the probability of the event that no matches occur.

Solution given:

```
P(no matches) = 1 - P(at least one match)
P(at least one match) = P(first match)+ P(second match) + P(third match) - P(first match and second match) -  P(first match and third match) -  P(second match and third match) +  P(first match and second match and third match)
P(at least one match) = (2!/3! * 3) -(1!/3! *3) +(1!/3!)
P(no match) = 1 - P(at least one match)
```

My question is why the Probability for each match is 2!/3!. Not sure how to get it. Need some guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P(first match) is the probability of matching the first respondent to the first addressee without regard to what the other matches are. Once you took the first mailing out of consideration, the remaining mailings can occur in $A_2 = 2!$ ways. The total # of mailing combinations is $A_3=3!$ ways, hence the answer.